# Table not shown in VBAs project explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel worksheet with two tables, tableOne and tableTwo. In VBAs project explorer, tableOne is shown (created first), tableTwo not ( created later). I need to create custom code for both tables and I would like to display them on the same worksheet. Looks like VBA allows only one table per worksheet. I verified this on another worksheet with two tables - same result. Googled for some hints but did not get anything. Please advise
You can easily try it yourself. Open a new workbook, got to first worksheet and create to tables there (i.e. format a range as table). If you open the VBA project explorer, you'll see only the table you created first. I'm not that expierienced in VBA and google did not provide much help. AFAIK, if I want to add custom code to an object (i.e. event handling), I need to attach it to the object. As second table is missing, no way of doing any event handling there

Comment: In VBE Project Explorer you can only see Workbooks, Sheets, Standard modules, Class modules and Forms, so I don't understand what you mean when you say that you see a table in Project Explorer. Could you explain what exactly you are trying to do with your tables and provide the code that you've written?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *In VBAs project explorer, tableOne is shown* If it's shown, then it's not a table, but it can be one of the objects suggested by @KirillTkachenko. The concept *Table* in Excel means **[this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)**

Comment: Cannot understand what Table you are referring to. Can your share your code, maybe that will have some hint.

Comment: You can easily try it yourself. Open a new workbook, got to first worksheet and create to tables there (i.e. format a range as table). If you open the VBA project explorer, you'll see only the table you created first.
I'm not that expierienced in VBA and google did not provide much help. AFAIK, if I want to add custom code to an object (i.e. event handling), I need to attach it to the object. As second table is missing, no way of doing any event handling there.